# We are developing a todo dApp and when we deploy it to a JavaScriptEVM both in Remix and Hardhat it costs 1.5m gas... Is it ok? Or is it enormous?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, dapp-design

This is the contract we are deploying:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract ToDoStorage {
    struct ToDoList {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
        string[2][] todos;
    }

    mapping(address => ToDoList[]) public addressToList;
    uint256 private _nonce = 0;

    function createToDoList(
        string memory name,
        string[] memory contents
    ) public {
        uint256 id = createId();
        string[2][] memory todos = new string[2][](contents.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
            todos[i] = [contents[i], "false"];
        }
        addressToList[msg.sender].push(ToDoList(id, name, todos));
    }

    function createTodo(uint256 todoListId, string memory content) public {
        (bool found, uint256 todoListIndex) = findToDoListIndex(todoListId);
        if (!found) return;
        addressToList[msg.sender][todoListIndex].todos.push([content, "false"]);
    }

    function updateTodo(
        uint todoListId,
        uint256 todoItemId,
        string[2] memory todo
    ) public {
        (bool found, uint256 todoListIndex) = findToDoListIndex(todoListId);
        if (!found) return;
        addressToList[msg.sender][todoListIndex].todos[todoItemId] = todo;
    }

    function retrieve(uint256 id) public view returns (string[2][] memory) {
        (bool found, uint256 todoListIndex) = findToDoListIndex(id);
        if (!found) return new string[2][](0);

        return addressToList[msg.sender][todoListIndex].todos;
    }

    function removeTodo(uint todoListId, uint256 todoItemId) public {
        (bool found, uint256 todoListIndex) = findToDoListIndex(todoListId);
        if (!found) return;
        delete addressToList[msg.sender][todoListIndex].todos[todoItemId];
    }

    function removeTodoList(uint todoListId) public {
        (bool found, uint256 todoListIndex) = findToDoListIndex(todoListId);
        if (!found) return;
        delete addressToList[msg.sender][todoListIndex];
    }

    function findToDoListIndex(uint256 id) public view returns (bool, uint256) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < addressToList[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            if (addressToList[msg.sender][i].id == id) {
                return (true, i);
            }
        }
        return (false, 0);
    }

    function createId() private returns (uint256) {
        _nonce++;
        return _nonce;
    }

    constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nah, that sounds about normal for a contract. For reference, a typical ERC20 contract costs about 1M to deploy, and a typical  ERC721 contract about 2.5M.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that seems standard deployment cost. If you want to deacrease the gas cost then you can check optimization, that will drastically decrease your gas cost. That is available in remix ide under `Advanced Configurations`

Comment: Thank you a lot!